# How do I maintain the Immersive Mode in Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-immersive

I use immersive-sticky mode to hide the navigation bar and action bar:

```
@TargetApi(19)
private void setImmersiveMode() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = getImmersiveUiOptions(decorView);
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (null!=actionBar) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

When a `Spinner` is touched, the `navigationBar` is shown and immersive mode is disabled.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207365) works for Dialogs:

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
context.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

But `Spinner` doesn't have `show()` method that I could overwrite.

How can I prevent System UI from showing when a Spinner is touched?

**Edit**: this question is about keeping the Navigation Bar hidden (BackButton, HomeButton and RecentTasksButton). I'm already using `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setSystemUIVsibility full screen disables when using Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146493/setsystemuivsibility-full-screen-disables-when-using-spinner)

Answer (score 7):

I know this is super late, but I finally found a solution to this [here](https://gist.github.com/kakajika/a236ba721a5c0ad3c1446e16a7423a63):

Just call this on your spinner before using it:

```
import android.widget.PopupWindow
import android.widget.Spinner

fun Spinner.avoidDropdownFocus() {
    try {
        val isAppCompat = this is androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        val spinnerClass = if (isAppCompat) androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner::class.java else Spinner::class.java
        val popupWindowClass = if (isAppCompat) androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow::class.java else android.widget.ListPopupWindow::class.java

        val listPopup = spinnerClass
                .getDeclaredField("mPopup")
                .apply { isAccessible = true }
                .get(this)
        if (popupWindowClass.isInstance(listPopup)) {
            val popup = popupWindowClass
                    .getDeclaredField("mPopup")
                    .apply { isAccessible = true }
                    .get(listPopup)
            if (popup is PopupWindow) {
                popup.isFocusable = false
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who, like me,  will start rewriting solution pasted by @Quinn from Kotlin to Java and later they will find out that on [the linked git repo](https://gist.github.com/kakajika/a236ba721a5c0ad3c1446e16a7423a63) is the solution in Java also, I am pasting it here:

```
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public static void avoidSpinnerDropdownFocus(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Field listPopupField = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
        Object listPopup = listPopupField.get(spinner);
        if (listPopup instanceof ListPopupWindow) {
            Field popupField = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popupField.setAccessible(true);
            Object popup = popupField.get((ListPopupWindow) listPopup);
            if (popup instanceof PopupWindow) {
                ((PopupWindow) popup).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, sorry about that!

Comment: No problem :) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I had a problem with this on Android 9 which was related to using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` version `1.0.2`. Upgrading to `1.2.0` avoided the problem and made this workaround work again.